# Long Stay Visa in Germany

Tags: visas, germany, long-stay-visas

I got selected to an incubator program in Germany and I'm a Sri Lankan citizen. I cannot seem to find the right type of visa I need to apply for. The Embassy told me it has to be Long Term Visa, but there are many categories. Does anyone know what I need to apply for? The program in Germany lasts for 6 months.

Comment: What categories ? I only know that you need a residence permit for a longer stay. You download or get the document from the embassy or mission, explain your reason and your visa is granted (or not). Could you explain in detail what kind of "categories" they are suggesting ?

Comment: Are you sure the visa is the critical point here? You'll need a work permit (probably the EU blue card), which has pretty strict requirements in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a working permit (i.e. a blue card). If you are planning to create a startup business in Germany from the incubator, you might have [better chances](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/Infoservice/FAQ/ArbeitenLebenDeutschland/02-own%20business.html?nn=479790). This requires you however to invest money and create jobs in Germany.

So in any case, you need a "[Blue Card](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/Infoservice/FAQ/ArbeitenLebenDeutschland/01-aaBlue%20Card%20english.html?nn=479790)". If you cannot claim to be a startup through your investment volume in Germany, you need an income of at least 44,800 euros p/a.

If this is also not possible, I would consult the incubator program directly to inquire how they would recommend the visa to be applied for.

Answer (score -4):

Why dont apply for a Schengen Visa? Category : Business.

http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/cae/servlet/contentblob/350388/publicationFile/164910/VisumantragEngl.pdf

They will interview you anyway at the embassy.

See also:

http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05_Legal/
02_*Directory*_Services/01_*Visa/*_Permanent_*Residence*_Visa.html

(cant get the whole link to work)

Comment: Schengen visa is only valid for 90 days, and the "business" category is for business travel, not for actually working and being paid in the visited country.

Comment: Yes. Seems you're right. The blue card you mentioned should be right.